# Progress Bar with process

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

When i click my command button it takes a few seconds to complete the process which could make the end users think the program is lagging, then i thought of the progress bar. so how can make the progress bar work while the process is running so that the users will not think that the program is lagging, i'm new to vb.net, i research quiet some time now and still can't get how it works nor how will i start.

thanks for the help in advance

this is my command button process.

```
        Private Sub LoginBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginBTN.Click
    Using ClientDashboardx As New ClientDashboard
        Try

            cn = New ADODB.Connection
            conDB()
            cn.Open()

            rs = New ADODB.Recordset
            rs.Open("SELECT * FROM tb_registration", cn, 0, 3)

            If txtuserid.Text = "" Or txtuserpass.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Value Null")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Do While Not rs.EOF
                    Dim strLogin = txtin.Text
                    Dim strLogout = txtout.Text
                    If rs("st_acc_number").Value = txtuserid.Text And rs("st_password").Value = txtuserpass.Text And rs("st_log").Value = strLogin Then
                        MsgBox("Account in use")
                        Exit Sub
                    ElseIf rs("st_acc_number").Value = txtuserid.Text And rs("st_password").Value = txtuserpass.Text And rs("st_log").Value = strLogout Then
                        Dim strID = rs("st_acc_number").Value
                        Dim strUserName = rs("st_fname").Value & " " & rs("st_lname").Value
                        Dim strTotalTime = rs("st_totaltimeleft").Value
                        rs.Close()
                        SaveAccNumber.Text = strID
                        SaveUserName.Text = strUserName
                        SaveTotalTime.Text = strTotalTime

                        cn.BeginTrans()
                        cn.Execute("UPDATE tb_registration SET st_log='in' where st_acc_number='" & SaveAccNumber.Text & "'")
                        cn.CommitTrans()
                        cn.Close()

                        ClientDashboardx.id_lbl.Text = SaveAccNumber.Text
                        ClientDashboardx.iduser_lbl.Text = SaveUserName.Text
                        ClientDashboardx.UserTotalTime.Text = SaveTotalTime.Text
                        ClientDashboardx.AutoUpdate_Button.Enabled = True
                        Me.Hide()
                        ClientDashboardx.ShowDialog()
                        Me.Show()
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        rs.MoveNext()
                    End If
                Loop
                MsgBox("User/Pass Mismatch")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Server Offline", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You should perform your long running process in a separate thread or [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Here is how to use the background worker:**

Add a BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar to your Form

Add a private variable to hold your result

```
Private _success As Boolean
```

Add code to show the ProgressBar and Start the worker in Form_Load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _success = False
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Perform your long running operation here

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'perform your db access here and set the result in _success
End Sub
```

When the worker has finished hide the progress bar and depending on the result perform some action

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    If _success Then
        Me.Hide()
        ClientDashboardx.ShowDialog()
        Me.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("User/Pass Mismatch")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a straight forward guide. this will save me so much time. cheers

Comment: I Have encountered an error, here
 
            SaveAccNumber.Text = strID
            SaveUserName.Text = strUserName
            SaveTotalTime.Text = strTotalTime

This is the error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Client' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." what should I do? this is the first time I saw an error like this.

Comment: You can't set the Text values of TextBoxes inside a background worker without using a delegate as it runs on a different thread (hence the error). Set values in variables and then use these variables to populate the textboxes in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: I've search about the error. and i found this. System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
is this a good code? seemed to work, but BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted doesn't seem to work.
so i put me.hide() clientdashboardx.showdialog() me.show in the DoWork. and it work.